# Cursor is returning the same rows multiple times from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have written the below method get get some selected rows by the help the id.

```
public ArrayList<IncidentCategoryHolder> getAllImageSource(String contractTypeId){
    ArrayList<IncidentCategoryHolder> data = new ArrayList<IncidentCategoryHolder>();
    Cursor cursor=null;

    cursor =  ourDatabase.rawQuery("select "+NAME+","+BACKGROUND_COLOR+" from " 
                          + INCIDENT_CATAGORY_TABLE + " where " 
                          + CONTRACT_TYPE_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contractTypeId });

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NAME));
        Log.v("Text", text);
        String png = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BACKGROUND_COLOR));

        IncidentCategoryHolder mHolder = new IncidentCategoryHolder();
        mHolder.setName(text);
        mHolder.setBackgroundColor(png);
        data.add(mHolder);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

        cursor.close();

    return data;
}
```

Its returning the perfect rows, but multiple times. Can any one please suggest me where I did the mistake here.

Comment: are you sure there  are not multiple results for your condition in database

Comment: maybe try also selecting the unique identifier for each tuple and logging it so you can be sure the rows are actually duplicates

Comment: @PramodYadav Your point is valuable for me. I'm not sure. let me check once.Thanks for the reply

Comment: @steve Thanks for a nice suggestion ..I am trying it now.